# How to install Hibernate Tools into Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I'm using Eclipse Luna, I want to create a web app and use Hibernate for my data. In Eclipse Marketplace I found Hibernate Tools for Indigo or Helios but not for Luna.

I found just Red Hat JBoss Developper Studio for Luna ( what's that ?).

Comment: One does not simply install Hibernate in Eclipse!

Comment: I have install hibernate for indigo, I have the different views of hibernate now...

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that you're asking about Hibernate Tools. Hibernate is a framework, so the original wording of your question made it sounds like you didn't have a clue. Make sure to be precise in your questions, and provide more detail than you think is needed.

Comment: I also have tried to install hibernate plugin in eclipse luna 4.4.1 linux version but it gives error while downloading plugin

Answer (score 18):

Hibernate Tools is part of JBoss Developer Studio. One option is to install (from Eclipse Marketplace) **Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio (Luna)**, which will include the entire suite of JBoss tools (including Hibernate Tools). If you just want the Hibernate Tools, you'll have to use *Help* > *Install New Software...* and then add the JBoss Tools update site (http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/). From there you can select just the Hibernate Tools (or anything else you want).

Comment: I have tried to install Red hat Jboss Developper, but eclipse tell me : Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while 2/15.

Comment: Alternative JBoss update source is `https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/updates/` or `https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/webtools/photon/`

Answer (score 6):

I use Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) version 4.4 Luna. Menu `Help \ Install new software...`

Add plug-in repository: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/

Search modules for `Hibernate` (Install all JBoss plug-ins is not good practice), then install

[image]
(open screenshot image in a new window for big size)

Answer (score 2):

just go to eclipse marketplace. 
type jboss tools luna.
install the plugin.
Done.