# Eclipse Luna: missing builder org.hibernate.eclipse.console.hibernateBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I recently installed Eclipse Luna on my Linux Mint
I've recently imported one project on my workspace

I was trying to configure jpa in project properties, when I went to jpa section I was wondering to find hibernate jpa platform but nothing.

So I went to **Builders**, and I saw *Missing builder(org.hibernate.eclipse.console.hibernateBuilder)*.

I'm googling from 3 hours but I found any solution.

Any idea how to solve?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to add the tools yourself, Help -> Install new.. Add JBoss tools update side http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/ and select hibernate tools.

Comment: Give credit to this guy if ever that works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389961/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-into-eclipse-luna