# Jpa,hibernate,mapping a table to a classe

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

I use jpa annotations, hibernate has generated for me an association table, related to a manyTomany annotation
How can i use this table as a java class?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your IDE (like NetBeans) to generate POJO classes from your existing database. These classes can then be used as normal java classes to interact with your database.

Follow this tutorial: [JPA and JAVAFX](https://ajimenezr.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/an-example-application-with-jpa-and-javafx/)

Comment: Thank you , i'll try to follow this tutorial.

Comment: i use eclipse ide, do i need to pursue the same steps?

Comment: Personally, I use NetBeans and have not much experience working in Eclipse. But may be this tutorial could help you with your query - [Step by step auto code generation for POJO domain java classes and hbm using Eclipse Hibernate plugin](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/step-by-step-auto-code-generation-for-pojo-domain-java-classes-and-hbm-using-eclipse-hibernate-plugin.html).

Comment: May be this can help you - [How to install Hibernate Tools into Eclipse Luna?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389961/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-into-eclipse-luna)